# Create a Connection between excel and Java

Tags: java, eclipse, excel, jframe

I have been working on a program where I need to save information into excel and then take the info from the excel spreadsheet that was saved eariler by a user.

My problem is that I am a new programmer so I dont know how to create a connection with excel and then save it as an excel file and retreive data from the file.

PS: I am working on the jframe

Comment: Take a look at [Apache Poi](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/). There are several tagged questions here on SO that you can browse before making a decision on whether or not to use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) for such need. Indeed `Apache POI` is a java library allowing to manipulate Microsoft Documents such as Excel.

For Excel here is the [home page](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html) and a nice [quick guide](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html).

Comment: Sure but i have one more question i just wanna understand something about apache poi : so if i install apache poi then its gonna be like  a method and then i can import when  9i wanna use excel or is it only a sample, and another thing how can i import the apache poi docs into eclipse

Comment: sorry again i have a question after installing apache poi what should i do step by step plz and quickly because a have a deadline to handout my program

Comment: thank u very much it worked and sorry again for asking lots of questions:)

Answer (score 0):

Excel and Java weren't exactly built to interact with each other but it can be done.

If you save the spreadsheet as a .csv file it can be interpreted by a Java program, like this: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-and-parse-csv-file-in-java/

That being said, it's much easier to work with JSON in Java (in my opinion) so once you've got a CSV file you can use this website to convert it: http://www.csvjson.com/csv2json Unfortunately this way you won't be able to use a JSON in Excel, whereas with the other way you can open the file for writing, write to it, close it, and be able to open it again with Excel.

If you have a choice, it would be better to use C# since it was also made by Microsoft and they like to make it easier to interact with their own file types.

Comment: i have no choice i tried downloading mysql but im encountering lots of issues trying to set up on my computer

Comment: @Beginnerprogrammer I don't see what this has to do with MySQL

Comment: u said before that excel is not the best way for a database generated by java language, and mysql is another database source. could u give me an easier database source to save data

Comment: i added the jars of apache poi 3.15 but i cant use it its telling me "source not found" plz help